# How to create an "add to calendar" iCal link (.ics file) from server data and send it back to my webApp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jersey, jax-rs

I am working on prototyping something, and I'm hoping someone can help me. I am trying to create an `Add event to calendar` link which will download and open an iCal file (.ics), so that they can add it to their calendar.

We are using Jax-RS with Jersey and tomcat as the container, and I have the `iCal4j` package. The client is jQuery/backbone.

1. I am not sure which is the correct way to return the data. If I should be creating an ics file and storing it somewhere before returning it, or sending back a CalendarOutputter filestream from iCal4j?
2. If I do create an ics file, where do I store that? WEB-INF folder? How?
3. If returning the filestream, what is the correct @Produces(?) for Jax-RX?

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not create a file to return the data. You should be able to return your Calendar object directly. Try something like:

```
@GET
@Path("calendar")
@Produces("text/calendar")
public Response generateCalendar() {
  Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
  // Generate your calendar here
  ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok();
  builder.header("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=calendar.ics");
  builder.entity(calendar.toString());
  return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: That's good way to go if you wanna stick  with Jersey. But really this kind of implementation bypasses most of Jersey's usefulness. You're better off just making a servlet, setting the response type to text/calendar or whatever the mime type of iCal is, grabbing the servlet Writer and writing your iCal file content through it.

Comment: Thanks @user463324. So now that I am returning 'calendar.toString()' any idea how I go about turning that into an .ics file for download?

Comment: I update my answer so it changes the `content-disposition`. If you go the servlet route as suggested by @Shivan you could do something similar...

Comment: Any idea how I handle the jQuery side? I've done what you suggested (which I also saw previously in another post), but I cannot get the 'filesave' popup? I read somewhere that I shouldn't be using an ajax call?

Comment: I figured it out, I think: `document.location = url + '?';` Seems to be working unless there is something better. Oh and we are sticking with jersey as this is only a small piece of the app. Thanks for all the help!